# How to make current :hover element be on top when all elements are using the same class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover

I am trying to create a simple bookshelf using pure CSS and HTML. However, I am struggling to **get the currently moused-over book to have the highest `z-index`.**

Is this possible without JS? Some clever use of CSS selectors perhaps?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/92vq05xr/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="bookshelf">
  <div class="book">
    <div class="side spine">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="side top">
    </div>
    <div class="side cover">
      Book 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="book">
    <div class="side spine">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="side top">
    </div>
    <div class="side cover">
      Book 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="book">
    <div class="side spine">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="side top">
    </div>
    <div class="side cover">
      Book 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bookshelf {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 800px; */
  margin-top: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  display: flex;
}

.book {
  width: 50px;
  height: 280px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(0) rotateY(0);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin: center left;
}

.spine {
  width: 50px;
  height: 280px;
  line-height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(0px);
}

.top {
  width: 50px;
  height: 190px;
  line-height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(95px) translateY(-95px);
}

.cover {
  width: 190px;
  height: 280px;
  line-height: 200px;
  background-color: cyan;
  left: 50px;
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(0);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.book:hover {
  transform: rotateX(-25deg) rotateY(-40deg) rotateZ(-15deg) translateY(50px) translateX(-30px);
}
```

Comment: do you mean you want the book to pop out of its position on hover or you want it to go up or you want it to go on the right or on top of the other books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `z-index` at `.book:hover`.

```css
.bookshelf {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 800px; */
  margin-top: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  display: flex;
}

.book {
  width: 50px;
  height: 280px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(0) rotateY(0);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin: center left;
}

.spine {
  width: 50px;
  height: 280px;
  line-height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(0px);
}

.top {
  width: 50px;
  height: 190px;
  line-height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(95px) translateY(-95px);
}

.cover {
  width: 190px;
  height: 280px;
  line-height: 200px;
  background-color: cyan;
  left: 50px;
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(0);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.book:hover {
  transform: rotateX(-25deg) rotateY(-40deg) rotateZ(-15deg) translateY(50px) translateX(-30px);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bookshelf">
  <div class="book">
    <div class="side spine">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="side top">
    </div>
    <div class="side cover">
      Book 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="book">
    <div class="side spine">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="side top">
    </div>
    <div class="side cover">
      Book 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="book">
    <div class="side spine">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="side top">
    </div>
    <div class="side cover">
      Book 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why I didn't even try that... too late to be coding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this maybe?? Let me know

```css
.bookshelf {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 800px; */
  margin-top: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  display: flex;
}

.book {
  width: 50px;
  height: 280px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(0) rotateY(0);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin: center left;
}

.spine {
  width: 50px;
  height: 280px;
  line-height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(0px);
}

.top {
  width: 50px;
  height: 190px;
  line-height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(95px) translateY(-95px);
}

.cover {
  width: 190px;
  height: 280px;
  line-height: 200px;
  background-color: cyan;
  left: 50px;
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(0);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.book:hover {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-100deg) rotateZ(-360deg) translateY(0px) translateX(5px);
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="bookshelf">
  <div class="book">
    <div class="side spine">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="side top">
    </div>
    <div class="side cover">
      Book 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="book">
    <div class="side spine">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="side top">
    </div>
    <div class="side cover">
      Book 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="book">
    <div class="side spine">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="side top">
    </div>
    <div class="side cover">
      Book 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```